# Is it possible to check if IE blocked my download with jQuery/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am having some issues with IE which is showing me its yellow "download blocked" bar for a good reason: the actual submit that returns the file is triggered due javascript. I would like the show the user some additional information if this is the case.

So is it possible the check if the browser is actually blocking my download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that is not possible :( That is there with the browser, you can't control it programatically.

I had created a vbscript code to disable that from registry in old WIN98 days but I belive it won't work now:

```
Sub DisableActiveXWarning ()
Dim SHL
Dim sReg

Set SHL = CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")

sReg = "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\0\1201"

If SHL.RegRead (sReg) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "ActiveX Warning is already disabled!",vbExclamation
Else
    SHL.RegWrite sReg,0,"REG_DWORD"

    If SHL.RegRead (sReg) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The ActiveX Warning was successfully disabled.",vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "An unknown error has occured !!",vbCritical
    End If
End If
Set SHL = Nothing
End Sub
```